# How to find index of fullwidth character in String?

Tags: java, string

I wrote a function to find a space (in full-width) in a `String`. But `indexOf` cant find it and returns `-1`. This is my function:

```java
public static String getflagCheck(String content) {

    List<String> supplierNames = Arrays.asList("//");
    String remark = "x";

    boolean flagValid = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < supplierNames.size(); i++) {
        int index =  content.indexOf(supplierNames.get(i));
        int indexTestPoint = content.indexOf("　");
        System.out.println(index);
        System.out.print(indexTestPoint + "\n\n");
        if(index > -1) {
                flagValid = true;
                if(indexTestPoint < index) {
                    flagValid = false;
                }
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(flagValid) {
        remark = "x";
    } else {
        remark = "needcheck";
    }
    return remark;
}
```

Comment: What does "space (in full-width)" mean? There is no space in Unicode named "full-width": [Unicode Characters in the 'Separator, Space' Category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm)

Comment: I believe this is what it refers to http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_full-width_chars.html

Comment: this is space in full-width katakana : "　".

Answer (score 0):

Your "space" at

```
int indexTestPoint = content.indexOf("　");
```

Isn't a space character but is a tab character. Replace it with a space.

Comment: this is a space in full-width character.

Comment: And does your input string `content` use full-width characters? Maybe update your question to show what inputs your are trying this with.

Comment: oh, thank you, i use input in file txt. I realize they has no different about space in txt. i think change type file is solution